# Pairwise z-test for evaluating classification accuracy

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

I'm fairly new to use of statistics in Remote Sensing, however I have seen the use of pairwise z-tests in several studies in assessing the accuracy of different classification techniques.

I have three classification techniques (MLC, SAM and SVM) employed using two different dimensionality reduction techniques (Principal Component Analysis and Minimum Noise Fraction transform).

I therefore have six Kappa statistics, one for each classification using each dimensionality reduction technique and would simply like to test for a statistical significance between them.

e.g MLC classification of PCA = 0.7,
    SAM classification of PCA = 0.6,
    SVM classification of PCA = 0.8,
    MLC classification of MNF = 0.7 etc

Can i use the standard Z-statistical test to statistically assess the difference between the kappa coefficients?

Thanks

Comment: Question is somewhat vague.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be more clear. Can i use the standard Z-statistical test to statistically assess the difference between the kappa coefficients?

Comment: No need to say sorry. You are new to the stats.stackexchange. I should welcome you to have joined us. You should edit your question in the light of your comment.